# How to optimize my code ("How many ways can you make the sum of a number?")

Tags: python, sum, set, python-itertools

I have a next code (This is the answer to the question "How many ways can you make the sum of a number?"):

```
import itertools


def exp_sum(n):
    l = [int(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    res = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for tup in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(l, i):
            if sum(tup) == n:
                res.extend(set(sorted(itertools.permutations(tup, i))))
    res = [tuple(sorted(q)) for q in res]
    print(len(set(res)))


exp_sum(int(input()))
```

How to speed up this code several times?

(If input is 11, running time is ~23s)

Comment: _sum of a number?_ what do you mean? if you have a `list`, use `sum(my_list)`

Comment: Do you mean (in this example) how many combinations of integers can be summed to 11? e.g., 1+10, 2+9, 1+1+1+1+7

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do a lot of sorting that is not needed. I give you to functions that perform a lot better.

To compare with input 11:

```
11.680076 # Your Function
0.10761999999999716 # a better Function keeping the tuples 
0.10596200000000522 # a function don't keep the tuples
```

```py
import time
import itertools


t = time.process_time()

elapsed_time = time.process_time() - t

def more_better_exp_sum(n):
    l = [int(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for tup in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(l, i):
            if sum(tup) == n:
                counter += 1
    print(counter)
        

def better_exp_sum(n):
    l = [int(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    res = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for tup in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(l, i):
            if sum(tup) == n:
                res.append(tup)
    print(len(res))
        


        
def exp_sum(n):
    l = [int(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    res = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for tup in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(l, i):
            if sum(tup) == n:
                res.extend(set(sorted(itertools.permutations(tup, i))))
    res = [tuple(sorted(q)) for q in res]
    print(len(set(res)))

x = int(input())


#YOur Version
t = time.process_time()
exp_sum(x)
print(time.process_time() - t)


# Number and tuples 
t = time.process_time()
better_exp_sum(x)
print(time.process_time() - t)

# Just the number 
t = time.process_time()
more_better_exp_sum(x)
print(time.process_time() - t)
```

Comment: I've added a faster solution if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the problem as removing *i* away from *n*, for each *i* from 1 to *n*, and recursively solving the problem for what's left, *n - i*, but removing no more than *i* or *n - i*, whichever is less, to avoid duplicates, until there is nothing left to remove, in which case there is only 1 way to remove nothing:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def exp_sum(n, m=float('inf')):
    if not n:
        return 1
    return sum(exp_sum(n - i, i) for i in range(1, min(n, m) + 1))
```

EDIT: Thanks to @donttalkjustcode for the cached version, which sped up the code by about 3 times given *n* = 11.

The benchmark below shows that this approach is about 3,000 times faster than @Kartoffelkultur's solution given *n* = 11:

```
161263.009 μs  Kartoffelkultur
77.217 μs  blhsing
54.968 μs  blhsing2
52.836 μs  blhsing3

160772.200 μs  Kartoffelkultur
65.117 μs  blhsing
51.606 μs  blhsing2
50.769 μs  blhsing3

224365.012 μs  Kartoffelkultur
62.634 μs  blhsing
50.885 μs  blhsing2
49.874 μs  blhsing3
```

[Run the benchmark online](https://tio.run/##pZPBitswEIbvfoq5LJG6aVjHUMqCYXvoqdAXCMEoXmkjVhoZSabdd@sz9JXSkRTbSdmWpfVJ0j/655vxaHiJR4fNx8GfTtoOzkfQUfronAmV8s5C1FZqOi1i2RVFjdjnwEk0fux60R9lVT1KBV8E@SglzfNo4ugZ8vsK6DPQwk5jZJqDch40aAQv8Emyeg0It1DzfY7s3YhEQ/F3ef@n6OI7RcRxSDFzHZve2YNGEbXD0H3T8dh5ORjRSyuJwqxBXzikTysIo2VkxKFtAa/VS7LbFuosekkl4nReVQ9zM9hXh5LnjhzMMWh8YrgG2@bj4kz50MXLPGe7K@@ENDvAe9DkopHp1AXa8de6ySzQGfLcJv53rO3/c20nsFd/baJNKd6O1BQkZZyIbKVRrfi/ojVvQpupqjTdgSbvtyleT2jzYjuvGrpFzt3i3JxpvQx0O9nt9vMkpwwpNGda6oj@5Xrekr7JDep6I4VnfJbl914OET7F6PVhjPKz985f3x5ECIs3EZQnzIywh0dxn91ZXXOaotEepG/rxX7w6ZmubjaNgp8/AqzgBliEd1DLD3Qhg3UdCiu7rtyiZPTqQBjDSs3p/Zyr393tc91nITWpCGTFjA6RWTEwI@k/TAJfltUCxE@nXw)

Comment: Nice Work! Thanks!

Comment: Pfft. Very slow. [Sped up version](https://tio.run/##pZJNbtswEIX3PMVsjJCNY1QxWgQBBKSLbnsBwxBoeRQT4B@GI6C@W8/QK7kkZUnptuWGGr6ZNx9HjFe@BL9/iXS7GRcDMRhG4hBsEgMFB2wcmnw6iYQRNU/KMPq@Js6ipbHrdX9BIc44wMlekvHv0m/BtT@CR/UqIC8zgA8MforKIuSRPDTiQ5BGJxcHeAKTXYyXeauRUjAEAgPGA2n/jrLZgnSQz7yCR2iUEuJtIZK1/0es5//nev5nMFFml6CdYbYLVZZyZrdWf7nTEabRcqk5HOtBySs2JbXardxM1zWouVnf1UF0vUVNUi0y/uwxMnxjJnMaGb8TBfq7OuqUVu9MUO47vQRptTud9euMt9Mxoj/L0lA2@a55KqM7IbXl3oshGc/yYbPbD/D7V4IH2IBk@AQNfs0VlbbrvHbYdVNVJsivErS1cuoEbTv3PHw@1mHchTK5SchW0prE0ukoLeb/PQtq/RQrkLrd/gA).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Thanks! I did think about memoization while writing the code but forgot about it in the end. What a difference indeed.

Comment: Yeah, and even more for larger `n`, not just 500 times faster then.

Comment: Just noticed that in your benchmark you only added the memoization. I think for a fair comparison, you should also clear the cache, like I did.

Comment: Oh darn, just realized you used `repeat`, not just `timeit`, so actually my benchmark was flawed as well.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Haha your benchmark code was so well written that it's now my default go-to code for any benchmarks. Just did not realize its pitfall for functions that are cached. I just posted two more versions of my code in the linked benchmark so that it's even faster. The fastest version may be considered ugly by your standard though. :-)

Comment: Hmm, I see you don't `repeat` anymore, but you increased `number` from 1 to 10. Now of course the nine last of those have the same issue...

Comment: Doh! Of course you're right. Don't know what I was thinking. Corrected the benchmark then. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, looks correct. Sadly only 3 times faster. Still faster for larger n, especially if you [don't limit the cache](https://tio.run/##rVLLasMwELz7K/YSIrVuiHFoS8DQHnrtD4RgZHedCPQwKxmaf@s39JdcWU6i9FioTlrNzuzsoP7kj9aUzz2NY0dWg5capQepe0v@XGUR6QbTemuVu4CKhroV7RGz7CXdP7CDRh2dNIeSmRx01SkrPFtK0y0532YQjuzAWA9mrqZD6AcyUGQ3hRs0S1LwADIHyaGzBBKkARLmgKwIM6SJozjcQ8H5rR/2bg3yW1eb/3O1@ZurbIrQQXXNJ796Cljg14lfnj0RukH5ibTbx4epb9KZWqNecuvplIrYG/BVjKFuFQpi/ArjZ4u9h1fvSTaDxzciS7/ZvXAuaQcH829gSujmQ2yjOnta8xzMoBukqkjyPUkT0l2syg6@vxwsYQHMwx0U@BgI0VhdG6GxrmdWGIbhUwml2LwzVNVl@916H/c@A1NIMxCkmJLOMy16pjCkfQF4umbJEB/HHw).

Comment: Argh that's right. Totally forgot about the default cache size not being unlimited. Thanks for being so thorough.

Comment: I'll give it another year or so before acting like everyone must be on Python 3.9+ so that I can just use `@cache` without remorse :-)